# Python: finding a common sublist of a given length present in two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, string-search

I have to find an efficient python code to do the following:

Find, at least one if existing, sequence of `n` consecutive elements which is included in the two given lists.

For example, with `n=3`, the result for these two lists will be `['Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill']`:

```
lst1 = ['John', 'Jim', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill', 'Chris']
lst2 = ['Chris', 'John', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill', 'Jim']
```

The sample code below does the trick, but it will take forever to do the same if I have to compare hundreds of thousands of rows/lists. Any advice on how to optimize the performance of this code for processing a very large amount of data will be greatly appreciated!

```
lst1 = ['John', 'Jim', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill', 'Chris']
lst2 = ['Chris', 'John', 'Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill', 'Jim']
strNum = 3 #represents number of consecutive strings to search for
common_element_found = 'False'
common_elements = []

lst1length = len(lst1) - (strNum - 1)
lst2length = len(lst2) - (strNum - 1)
for x in range(lst1length):
    ConsecutiveStringX = lst1[x] + ' ' + lst1[x + 1] + ' ' + lst1[x + 2]
    for y in range(lst2length):
        ConsecutiveStringY = lst2[y] + ' ' + lst2[y + 1] + ' ' + lst2[y + 2]
        if ConsecutiveStringY == ConsecutiveStringX:
            common_element_found = 'True'
            common_elements.append(ConsecutiveStringY)
            print('Match found: ' + str(common_elements)) 
            break
    if common_element_found == 'True':
        common_element_found = 'False'
        break
```

Comment: 1) You've tagged both 2.7 and 3.x - which one is it? 2) Do you need the matches to be at the same indices in both lists?

Comment: this may help:https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108052/finding-most-common-contiguous-sub-lists-in-an-array-of-lists

Comment: can you state your objective to ensure I haven't misunderstood your code? an example? also do you want a better way or just to make your way faster?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.0...doesn't matter what indices

Comment: Srini, I'm open to ideas, but most importantly the fastest way while achieving the desired results

Comment: Do you want the first matching occurrence only, are all?

Comment: First matching occurrence only

Answer (score 4):

IIUC,

```
consecs1 = [ tuple(lst1[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(lst1)-2)]
consecs2 = { tuple(lst2[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(lst2)-2)}

for c in consecs1: 
    if c in consecs2:
         print(c)
```

Output

```
('Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill')
```

---

Explanation: you can make a list of `tuples` for `lst1`, which are hashable objects, and check if they are `in` the `set` of `tuples` built from `lst2` (which grants O(1) speed).

*PS: Even though sets are unorded, order is guaranteed because the loop follows `lst1` and not `lst2` ordering.*

Comment: Thank you RafaelC for a quick response. I will give it a try later tonight and see how much faster it will be.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, consecs2 is just a set of all the 3 consecutive tuples in lst2. Note the `{` in the RHS of the `consecs2` declaration. Also I had no idea Python had set comprehension in the same way as list comprehension. Nice trick :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist `consecs2` is built from `lst2`, and `consecs1` from `lst1`. They are not necessarily equal

Comment: @RafaelC. OIC. Totally missed the number :)

Comment: @RafaelC you could also make `consecs1` a generator instead of a list, and then do something like `next((' '.join(c) for c in consecs1 if c in consecs2), None)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets:

```
>>> {tuple(lst1[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(lst1)-2)} & {tuple(lst2[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(lst2)-2)}
{('Tom', 'Sam', 'Jill')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expresions:

```
import re

re.search("((?:\w+ ){3}).*\\1"," ".join(lst1)+","+" ".join(lst2)).group(1)

'Tom Sam Jill'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3

stringlst2 = '#'.join(lst2)
for ngram in [lst1[i:i+n] for i in range(len(lst1)-n+1)]:
    if '#'.join(ngram) in stringlst2:
        print(ngram)
        break
```

Comment: but what about something like the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)? because it is a hack to concatenate the strings...